# How to overlap sprites in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How will I show 2 sprites on same layer. Presently sprites with horizontal image is coming behind the other sprites. Horizontal image sprites drawing in CCRibbon class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could assign them a z order. This is done by using code like this:

```
[self addChild: MySprite z:1]
```

The higher the z order, the highest up the sprite will be.